# Facing problems while using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` but the program seems to run forever when it reaches `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK`. The previous 2 steps : `CREATE_TASK` and `CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID` are working fine but i am not sure why the program runs forever when it reaches `RUN_TASK`.

```
-- create task and create chunks by rowid
L_sql := 'DELETE FROM sample_table WHERE <some_codition>
AND rowid BETWEEN :start_id AND :end_id';
DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK('test_task',
                                L_sql, 
                                DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                       parallel_level => 10)
    L_try := 0;
  L_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.TASK_STATUS('test_task');
  WHILE(l_try < 2 and L_status != DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.FINISHED) 
  LOOP
    L_try := l_try + 1;
    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RESUME_TASK('test_task');
    L_status := DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.TASK_STATUS('test_task');
  END LOOP;


  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.DROP_TASK('test_task');
```

Should i prefix the table name with schema name before sending my L_sql to run_task procedure? I am not able to figure out what to do, please help.

Comment: Highlighted key words

Answer (score 0):

All DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE is doing is in effect, running multiple database sessions using the Scheduler, and each of those is running a DELETE statement.  The "create_chunks_..." routines are the means via which you tell the database how to segment that delete command so that the sessions **will not overlap.**

Hence your statement

```
L_sql := 'DELETE FROM sample_table WHERE <some_codition>'
```

is going to have problems because there is nothing in there to segment the data.  In fact, you'll have "n" scheduler sessions all trying to delete the same rows (all of them).  Hence (n-1) of them will be blocked.

Change that to

```
L_sql := 'DELETE FROM sample_table WHERE <some_codition> 
          AND rowid BETWEEN :start_id AND :end_id'
```

so that when each task is run, the bind variables start_id/end_id will be passed the subset of table rowid's pertinent to each task.

Comment: Connor, sorry, my SQL has the placeholders. I just forgot to mention it here, let me correct that. Despite this, the SQL still runs forever when it reaches run_task. Should i prefix the schema name to the table name in the SQL? Or am i missing any setups that needs to be done before using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE ?

Comment: Take a look at v$session for the active scheduler jobs.  You can see where they are spending their time.  Might be a locking issue, or perhaps resource contention.

Comment: Connor, I found the problem, the parallel level parameter in the run task (parallel_level => 10) was causing the issue. For some wired reason It doesn't like 10, when i set it to 1, the program ran fine. But i didn't have this problem when i ran in another instance. I just checked the v$parameter table, i found that the thread value was 0 for this instance and 1 for the instance where it runs fine with any parallel value. Any thoughts on this? I think the problem is much beyond this and i am unable to see through.

Comment: Thanks to oracle documentation which doesn't say a thing about all these mysterious parameters involved behind the scenes, I wasted 3 days on this and almost lost my job implementing dbms_parallel_execute.!! Phew,

Comment: Check the job_queue_processes parameter.  If that is zero, no scheduler jobs will run